# Laravel, валидация файла, чтобы пропускало только GPX и CSV

Tags: php, laravel, валидация, site

Не могу сделать валидацию для файла, чтобы пропускало только файлы в форматах GPX и CSV
Пробовал и через mimes, и через mimetypes, названия форматов писал и маленькими, и большими буквами, и через точку, и без точки. При любом варианте блочит все файлы, в том числе и GPX/CSV
Ниже пример конструкции:

```
'file' => ['required','file','mimes:jpg,csv']
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло вот это  `mimes:csv,txt,xml`